# What will happen if we only have one candidate?

Tags: discussion, election

So far, we've only had one candidate step forward and nominate themselves.

What happens if there are no more candidates? Does the one candidate just move straight into being a moderator? Do we hold a one candidate election just to verify that they can get a few votes? Do we try really hard to scare up more candidates so we have an election?

Comment: see this chat thread: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14101838#14101838

Comment: This question is obsolete, since we now have multiple candidates.